# How to create a debian package to delivering fonts to users local directory?

Tags: fonts, deb, user-profile

I want to distribute few fonts that packaged within a debian package. Fonts should go to '~/.fonts' directory not to '/usr/share/fonts'. So every user can install fonts locally, not effecting system fonts.

I am almost certain about creating a debian package and tried creating one. But when I tried to install, it asks me for superuser privileges.

Please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use dpkg to install someting without root priviliges since it tries to touch the package database. But you can extract them:

```
dpkg -x your_package.deb ~/.fonts
```

But this is far away what you want I think. You can use a small script instead of dpkg maybe. So, users can copy fonts without using dpkg or superuser priviliges.

Comment: So, debian packaging should not be the option to distribute in this case. Thanks for info.